# How to solve "Catastrophic failure"

Tags: unity-game-engine, dllregistration

I get a

```
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

during use method of `lobject.dll` which was referred on my project.

```
UnityApplication giris = new UnityObjects.UnityApplication(); ***instance from .dll***

if (giris.Connect()) // ***this line is throwing that error***
{

}
```

Comment: See [Confusing error E_UNEXPECTED(0x8000FFFF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232883/confusing-error-e-unexpected0x8000ffff)

Comment: You can check this entry: [Catastrophic failure on IIS Web Service when calling a COM method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818152/catastrophic-failure-on-iis-web-service-when-calling-a-com-method)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while trying to login. Sometime it succeeded magically but most of times it raise `Catastrophic failure` exception. This approach worked for me:

1- run regedit as administrator
2- Find and delete 2 lbs directories
3- If the logo is installed on the server, go to the network (especially from the map) register.bat run the file as administrator, if it gives an error, make all the register records successfully so that you don't get an error, then run the logo first. This is really important
4- Run sys as administrator and renew license
5- Check if the user is fully authorized with `lobject` in sys
6- Try to connect with object again.

**Login Example:**

```
var UnityApp = new UnityObjects.UnityApplication();
UnityApp.LGSetup(@"Z:\", @"Z:\", 1, 1);
UnityApp.Disconnect();
if (!UnityApp.Login("myUsername", "myPassword", 1))
{
    var message = UnityApp.GetLastErrorString();
    MessageBox.Show(
        "Login Failed" +
        Environment.NewLine +
        message);

    return;
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Login Succeeded");
```

> I mapped logo path to drive Z. So your path should be different.

You can refer to [LGSetup Documents](https://docs.logo.com.tr/public/wua/logo-objects/logo-objects-kuetuephanesi/unityapplication/lgsetup) and [Login Documents](https://docs.logo.com.tr/public/wua/logo-objects/logo-objects-kuetuephanesi/unityapplication/login)