# Catastrophic failure on IIS Web Service when calling a COM method

Tags: visual-studio, iis, com, x86

Maybe the worst type of error message that one can see. Does not mean anything, may be related to everything...

I try to create a web service (WS) on IIS 7.5 *(I have initially tried WCF services but same story)* 
The WS uses a COM DLL which is successfully registered and the COM security permissions are given.

When I run the WS using Visual Studio Development Server everything is fine, I get the results as requested. But when I try to deploy the WS to IIS, I end up with

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Catastrophic failure
```

My computer has Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, x64.
I have to emphasize: I develop *(using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate)*, test *(using Visual Studio Development Server)* and deploy *(using IIS 7.5)* on the **same computer**.

I was thinking that the problem might be related to **32-64 bit incompatibilities**, as my COM is supporting 32 bits. Therefore, I changed the application pool settings to enable 32 bit applications, changed the platform target to x86 in Visual Studio, redeployed the WS, none of these helped.

My question is:

**How can a WS successfully run on VS Development Server but fail on IIS?** What else shall I change in IIS settings?

Comment: try installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable (64/32)

Comment: The name of the error code is better, E_UNEXPECTED.  Which is accurate, you didn't expect it :)

Comment: Did you find any solution about the error? I got the same error but could not find any solution yet.

Comment: I met same problem when i trying to connect to mysql database through   MS-office-visio's ODBC

Comment: @ftuna: I have received the solution from the provider. Actually, the COM registration process was not fully documented and all my "natural" assumptions were wrong. I strongly recommend to contact to the providers...

Comment: Thanks Bilal. Finally, someone from provider checked our system and then they find the problem. The problem is that on 64 bit system only EXE version is used as COM not DLL. However, in installation, they first registered DLL and some time later they realized that EXE should be used on 64 bit system and then without unregistering the DLL they register EXE. This is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really helps to consult the producer of the COM DLL. They have given a clear installation procedure for the DLL, that I have somehow omitted.

Moral of the story: Although your web service or web site operates successfully under Visual Studio Development Server, this does not necessarily mean that you have configured all settings for the COM DLL correctly.

You can start checking the following issues:

- Register the COM DLL
- Check configuration settings using **dcomcnfg**
- If your DLL does not appear in dcomcnfg lists, then probably you did not register it correctly. Some registry editor entries are probably missing.
- Check your IIS application pool settings
- You may need to impersonate in web.config
- Check the event viewer. It might include some important clues

In my case, I was playing with all of these items, but never in the correct sequence. Finally the help from the producer has arrived which was showing the correct path.

Comment: @ftuna: There is not one, single correct path, because there are millions of different COM DLLs around. If you are still curious :-) in my case, the provider has told us to unregister the DLL and register somewhat similar EXE version, adding some undocumented registry keys, and giving appropriate access rigths. And I feel that the provider wants to keep this registration process a secret as they make money from the implementations...